# VNDetectBarcodesRequest not working on iOS16

Tags: swift, vision, ios16, xcode14

I am experiencing issues with `VNDetectBarcodesRequest` on iOS 16. My code works as intended on iOS 15 but on iOS 16 it doesn't find any bar codes in an image.

I've separated my code to a playground and am experiencing the same issue here. Running the code below on Xcode 13.4.1's playground, I get the result:

> "Google link: Optional("https://www.google.com")"

Running the same code on Xcode 14, I get an `nil` result. Running this in an iOS15 simulator with Xcode 14 gives a positive result, only on iOS16 and playground it is not reading the QR code.

To add to it, no exceptions are thrown either.

Has anybody experienced the same and managed to fix this?

This is my playground code:

```swift
import UIKit
import Vision

extension UIImage {
    func qrCodeLink(completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: self) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage,
                                                        orientation: .up,
                                                        options: [:])       
        let request = VNDetectBarcodesRequest { (request,error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            guard let observations = request.results as? [VNDetectedObjectObservation] else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            let result = (observations.first as? VNBarcodeObservation)?.payloadStringValue
            completion(result)
        }
        try? imageRequestHandler.perform([request])
    }
}

if let google = UIImage(named: "google") {
    google.qrCodeLink { link in
        debugPrint("Google link: \(link)")
    }
} else {
    debugPrint("No google image")
}
```

With the above code I am using this image, which is merely a link to `https://www.google.com`:
[image: Google]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elaborating on @Paul Peelen's solution, to ensure that the workaround is only used where needed (Xcode 14 + iOS 16 + Simulator), we used:

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(simulator) && compiler(>=5.7)
if #available(iOS 16, *) {
    request.revision = VNDetectBarcodesRequestRevision1
}
#endif
```

Comment: Given this is more sustainable for a long term approach, I've accepted your answer as the correct one. Nice job! I am, however, wondering if we should use this revision at all since it is not officially documented on the VNDetectBarcodesRequest page. I've filed a feedback ticket to Apple about this.

Answer (score 6):

I think I've found the issue.
When running the request on Xcode 14 and iOS 16, the request revision runs on [`VNDetectBarcodesRequestRevision3`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectbarcodesrequestrevision3) (which issn't documented yet on [VNDetectBarcodesRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectbarcodesrequest) page). However, using [`VNDetectBarcodesRequestRevision1`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectbarcodesrequestrevision1) or [`VNDetectBarcodesRequestRevision2`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectbarcodesrequestrevision2) works.

Adding the following before the perform task worked for me:

```swift
request.revision = VNDetectBarcodesRequestRevision1
```

Comment: Thank you! We've been noticing the same issue, and this fixed it.

One clarification:

1) In iOS 15 Simulator, the request uses Revision2 by default, and succeeds.
2) In iOS 16 Simulator, the request uses Revision3 by default, and fails.
3) In iOS 16 Simulator, if you manually specify Revision2, it _also_ fails.

_Only_ by specifying Revision1 does it work for iOS 16 Simulator (at least in the Xcode 14.1 beta)

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. In Xcode 14 (not 14.1 beta) it seems that for us both rev 1 and 2 are working. Same goes for the playground code I posted above. I am not 100% sure if rev 3 was intended to be released due to IMHO it should continue to work with rev 3, but also it should be documented which Apple hasn't done. Maybe this is a bug in iOS 16 or iOS 16 simulator? I've filed FB11543049. 

Answer (score 0):

When compiling for either iOS 15 or 16, I found a difference in VNDetectedBarcodesRequest behavior when scanning a barcode WITH, or a barcode WITHOUT, a border. That border seems to trigger the scanning code when to start.

WITH a border: it scans both black-background image and white-background image correctly.

WITHOUT a border: it scans the barcode image on the monitor with a black background correctly, but it fails when that image is printed on white paper and scanned.  No border = no barcode.

NEW ISSUE: it returned an array of 17 identical barcode observations when it scanned that single bordered barcode.

Comment: On the NO BORDER aspect - the VNDetectedBarcodesRequest is failing to draw the entire barcode into its rectangle for analysis.  In a scan that is only slightly tilted, it is placing the four points of the rectangle in a way that may cut out part of the first or last vertical bars (on a code39 barcode without border). On the "New Issue" of 17 observations... they are 17 identical observations, presumably of descending probabilities. Suggestion: the developer could toss any identical guesses of lower probability before returning the array to the application.